# Access On-Premises data from Salesforce

Tags: oauth2, identity, activedirectory, identity-provider

Active Directory is used to store user and permissions. Salesforce needs to access some documents from an on-premise system. This should be restricted to certain users only.

I am thinking this can be achieved by Oauth and Active Directory. Salesforce will call the API on behalf of the user and then he will be redirected to AD and then authenticate and approve the request. Once done the user can see details from the API response.

Identity connect is used for user provisioning.

So in the flow, I mentioned doing we need Identity Connect or another identity provider? Or the requirement can be met by Salesforce, On-premise system, and AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have what you need.
Identity connect only does the AD to salesforce user sync/management, I believe.

Salesforce natively supports oauth & SAML.
You need to expose your document management system via the firewall, so salesforce can make requests to retrieve.
Is there an API to access these docs? Or are they on a file server?

If API, create a Named Credential entry for your api endpoint, and make apex callouts to that named credential.

If no api, check out an app exchange solution to access file servers: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/category/documents